# What to do when form choice field depends on value of domain object property

Tags: symfony

What should I do when a form choice field depends on property of 
domain object. I have insurance field that should contain insurances 
of specific user.

http://pastie.org/2132730

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the insurance choices are a known value of the user, then you can pass them in as options when you create your form:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new AgentContractFormType(), $agentContract, array(
    'insurances' => array(/* insurance choices here */),
));
```

then in your form class:

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'insurances' => $options['insurances'],
        'data_class' => 'NTO\DocumentBundle\Entity\Document\AgentContract',
    );
}
```

You can then use them in `buildForm()` as you please. Hope that helps.

Comment: Alternatively can pass smth trough DI to form type as well, but your approach is what I went with finally (just instead of 'insurances' 'repository' + 'userId' in options)